# boost ptime from sql server timestamp_t is off by minutes. What did I do wrong?

Tags: c++, sql-server-2005, boost-date-time, dtl-cpp

I have a SQL server database and I am pulling dates from it and converting the type of timestamp_t into Int64 as such:

```
Int64 from_timestamp_t(dtl::timestamp_t& t)
{
    // create a new posix time structure
    boost::posix_time::ptime pt
    (
    boost::gregorian::date           ( t.year, t.month, t.day),
    boost::posix_time::time_duration ( t.hour, t.minute, t.second, t.fraction )
    );

    ptime epoch(date(1970, Jan, 1));
    boost::posix_time::time_duration fromEpoch = pt - epoch;

    // return it to caller
    return fromEpoch.total_milliseconds();
}
```

I attempt to convert back to a boost ptime from an Int64 as such:

```
ptime from_epoch_ticks(Int64 ticksFromEpoch)
{
    ptime epoch(date(1970, Jan, 1), time_duration(0,0,0));
    ptime time = epoch + boost::posix_time::milliseconds(ticksFromEpoch);

    return time;
}
```

For some reason, and I can't figure out why, my dates, hours, etc are all correct, but my minutes are ahead a few minutes from what they should be.  Is it because timestamps from the database are in seconds resolution and I'm using milliseconds?  How do I fix this?

Applying the following modification as Dan suggested seems to have fixed the problem:

```
Int64 from_timestamp_t(dtl::timestamp_t& t)
{
    int count = t.fraction * (time_duration::ticks_per_second() % 1000);

    boost::posix_time::ptime pt
        (
        boost::gregorian::date           ( t.year, t.month, t.day ),
        boost::posix_time::time_duration ( t.hour, t.minute, t.second, count )
        );

    ptime epoch(date(1970, Jan, 1), time_duration(0, 0, 0, 0));

    boost::posix_time::time_duration fromEpoch = pt - epoch;

    return fromEpoch.total_milliseconds();
}
```

Comment: Dan's answer did the trick, I modified my solution above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with SQL Server 2005, but boost posix time has the *seconds* function if ticksFromEpoch is equivalent to one second.

```
ptime time = epoch + boost::posix_time::seconds(ticksFromEpoch);
```

However, the generic way to handle this is presented in the boost date_time [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#date_time.posix_time.time_duration):

> Another way to handle this is to utilize the ticks_per_second() method
>   of time_duration to write code that is portable no matter how the
>   library is compiled. The general equation for calculating a resolution
>   independent count is as follows:

```
count*(time_duration_ticks_per_second / count_ticks_per_second)
```

> For example, let's suppose we want to construct using a count
>   that represents tenths of a second. That is, each tick is 0.1 second.

```
int number_of_tenths = 5; // create a resolution independent count -- 
                          // divide by 10 since there are
                          //10 tenths in a second.
int count = number_of_tenths*(time_duration::ticks_per_second()/10);
time_duration td(1,2,3,count); //01:02:03.5 //no matter the resolution settings
```

Comment: I find that if I convert to a time_t first and then to a ptime using from_time_t then return total_milliseconds as before it comes out correctly.  There has to be something wrong with constructing my posix_time from gregorian and time_duration, but I still don't see it.